# Get the KB or speed of a download in .NET

Tags: .net, download, httpwebrequest, webclient

Right now i use either HttpWebRequest or WebClient to download files. I would like to see how many kbytes per second i am currently downloading at. How may i do this?

Comment: you have the count of bytes right? So start a timer, and work out the rate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good project that will show you how to do this using httpwebrequest:

http://stuff.seans.com/2009/01/05/using-httpwebrequest-for-asynchronous-downloads/

Here is a good msdn article on the process:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx

Here is an event you can use, if using the webclient:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The most easy way is to use
**WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged**

```
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.DownloadProgressChanged += MyCounterHandler;
                        client.DownloadFileCompleted += MyDoneHandler;
                        client.DownloadFileAsync(URI, tmpPath);
                    }
```